# viewport user-scalable=yes and media queries

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I took over the build of a website in which was NOT designed to be on mobile devices at all. The client needs to be able to at least navigate through the site via a mobile device so I am trying to make it so the site appears exactly the same on the mobile device as it does on the browser and just let the client pinch and zoom throughout it. I had to make some small adjustments via media queries but that's another story.

The site looks great with `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes" />` but it doesn't look like any of my media queries are taking effect... When I put `width=device-width` in the meta tag the site blows up and looks like its displayed at 300% zoom. When I put any of the following `initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0` I get the same effect I do when I just put `width=device-width`

So far the only thing that has given me close to what I am looking for is `user-scalable=yes` alone in the meta tag with nothing else, but the media queries aren't taking effect. Is it required to have `width=device-width` or `initial-scale` for media queries?

Here is the one media query I am using that is not taking effect:

`@media only screen and (max-width: 879px) {}`

Answer (score 3):

bro try this one.
i am explaining as per my knowledge but confident enough that it may help u

use meta tag like this

```
ex:<meta name='viewport' content=' width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1'  />
```

"width=device-width" 
tells that the width of your viewport is taken by the device's width

hence write media query for device width like this

ex:@media screen and (max-device-width:(your desired) px){}

try varying the given value to initial-scale: ranges from 0.0-1.0;

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think this is a misunderstanding about `width=device-width` the reason for using this is to make your site responsive, but what you are talking about is just a standard site, why don't you try the following

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=879">
```

this will cause the phone/device to view the site using this width initially, you shouldn't need any further viewport declarations for this to work the way you want

Comment: Thanks for this, but I suppose my real question is "Is the `width=` meta tag required for media queries to take effect? Or should they work with just `user-scalable=yes`? They don't seem to be working with just `user-scalable=yes`

Comment: well the media queries effectively work on the size of the page, so by forcing the page to scale to the width of the device, you are effectively keeping the page size the same, this is why your media queries aren't working. you may be better off with a specific css for mobile?